# Does Google Dialogflow Java API secure?

Tags: java, dialogflow-es

I want to know how Google Dialogflow API sends a request to the Google Dialowflow server.

And how does the request message is secured?

Does it have anything to do with OAuth 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All google java APIs use the same security mechanism.

You have to add an environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` that points to your credential file. The Java client library will take care of the authentication for you.

So yes. Google's APIs are secure.

You can find detailed information about the whole authentication flow here:
https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/quick/setup#auth